# iOS - beginning iOS tutorial - underscore before variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

I am starting to learn how some iOS development at the minute and I currently have the Apress beginning IOS6 book that I am working off.

In chapter two there is a simple tutorial to show two buttons and a label and when a button is pressed it is shown on the label which one was pressed.

I have completed the tutorial but it has raised one question that I can't find the answer to.

The tutorial uses ARC (automatic reference counting) in case that makes a difference.

Here is the code,

The header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MTMViewController : UIViewController


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;


- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

And the m file:

```
#import "MTMViewController.h"    

@implementation MTMViewController

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {


    NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSString *plainText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed.", title];

    statusLabel.text = plainText;


}

@end
```

The above is how it appears in the book, however when doing the tutorial in Xcode I could not compile with the following line:

```
statusLabel.text = plainText;
```

And instead had to change it to:

```
_statusLabel.text = plainText;
```

When I done this the code compiled and ran fine, I tried to figure out why this happened by going back through the tutorial to see if I missed anything but I didn't see anything.

Can anyone explain why the code in the book didn't compile and why I had to add the underscore to the front of the variable? Is this correct or have I done something wrong?

Comment: There is concept of "@synthesize" for generating getters and setters. If you declare that property with "@synthesize" than you can directly access with the same name. Just for reference.

Comment: @Jennis I really wouldn't recommend that, as that'll cause confusion as to whether you're accessing the underlying variable, or via the generated getter/setter. Having different names for different ways of access makes it clear what the code is doing, and its rationale. If using older versions of Xcode where `@synthesize` is mandatory for properties, I'd recommend the form `@synthesize statusLabel = _statusLabel`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason `statusLabel.text = plainText;` failed is because you were not accessing the property correctly. In order to access it through the generated getters/setters, you need to prepend `self.` to it, as the property (and its setters/getters) belongs to the instance of self. So instead it would be `self.statusLabel.text = plainText;`

The reason `_statusLabel` worked is because this is the underlying variable that holds the value for the property. You are circumventing the generated setters/getters when accessing the variable this way. Generally, you should use `self.propertyName`, as this will respect the keywords you have provided as part of the property definition (a good example is if you use the `atomic` keyword, as the generated setters and getters will correctly place a `@synchronized` block around the underlying instance variable).

Recent versions of Xcode create the variable name with a prepended underscore if you don't manually synthesize your properties (which is an OK thing to do, previously people **had** to synthesize manually). You can define your own underlying variable name if you so wish, using `@synthesize statusLabel = m_statusLabel`. This mean you can access it using `m_statusLabel` instead of `_statusLabel`. You shouldn't need to do this usually, unless there is a dire need to; Apple suggests using a prepended underscore.

You should use the underlying variable when in initialising methods, and deallocating methods, as the generated setters/getters may not be complete when at this point in the code.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that, great information. So I'm guessing the code in the book is incorrect in this case and I should use self.property when reading future chapters in the book?

Comment: If the code you've posted is exactly like in the book, then yes the book is wrong. You should use `self.statusLabel`. I can see where they've slipped up; when I mentioned people had to manually synthesize properties, you could just use `@synthesize statusLabel`. This would create an underlying variable with the name `statusLabel`, which exacerbates the confusion to the untrained eye of whether you were using generated setters/getters or the underlying variable!

Comment: Actually I left out one thing that's not in the book but is in the source code with the book which is the line @synthesize statusLabel; in the .m file which is what you say there. I'm still a little confused, am I better off using the self.property approach or the [@]synthesize property approach?

Comment: The `@synthesize` is done automatically for you in recent versions of Xcode, and you don't need to do it yourself (if you have to, you'll know, but use a different underlying variable name). I personally suggest using `self.property` everywhere, except in `init` and `dealloc` methods, where you should use `_property`.