# Beginning iOS 6 Development - self.statusLabel.text build failure

Tags: ios

It is never a good sign when a beginners book has errors related to source in the third chapter, but here I am with Beginning iOS 6 Development from Apress. We are working on a simple project that gives two buttons and changes a label based on the name of the button being pressed.

The initial request by the book was to use **`statusLabel.text = plainText;`**, but that failed.

This was previously discussed on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771197/ios-beginning-ios-tutorial-underscore-before-variable), so I modified it to **`self.statusLabel.text = plainText;`**, but that didn't resolve my issue.

Here is my code:

```
#import "BIDViewController.h"

@implementation BIDViewController

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *plainText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@button pressed.", title];
    self.statusLabel.text = plainText;

} 

@end
```

The error being thrown is the following: **Property 'text' not found on object 'UIView *'**

I'm guessing this is something stupid, but I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: When you use self in front of an Object then it is considered as a property. If you don't want to create a property of your status label then remove 'self' from statusLabel.text and just write this instead  [statusLabel setText:plainText];

Answer (score 6):

The error is spelled out pretty nicely,

> Property 'text' not found on object 'UIView *'

Meaning you probably declared statusLabel as a UIView. Something like:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *statusLabel;
```

When it should have been declared as a UILabel:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
```

It is important to keep in mind that even though `UILabel` does inherit from `UIView`, that doesn't mean they share all the same properties/methods. In this case, the `UILabel` subclass of `UIView` declares a property `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;` which does not exist in its superclass (`UIView`).